# cakephp 1.2 good simple authetication sample

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I was trying several authentication samples for cakephp 1.2 but didn't find any flawless piece of code. Can you suggest me some code? 
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I've always used the [example in the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication), it's simple, straight forward and works.

Comment: Example n the cookbook is the best one.

Comment: yes, from the book is just basic, i would like to see some registration, confirmation, reset password...features

Answer (score 0):

I have used DarkAuth in the past (http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/darkauth-another-way) and found it pretty straightforward to implement.

Comment: what version of cake 1.1 or 1.2?